# Current solution for GridView inside Scrollview?

Tags: android, gridview

I have an Activity in my app that requires the following in this order:

```
<TextView />
<ExitText />
<GridView />
<Button />
```

I want them all to be in a `ScrollView` so that the user can (must) view all of the items in the `GridView` before hitting the `Button`. The problem is that `GridView` has its own scrolling mechanism and it wouldn't make sense to nest them inside of `ScrollView`. I want to expand the `GridView` so that it loses its scrolling yet displays all its content. I saw some solutions on SO that had some code to implement a custom `GridView`, but those were pretty old. Does Android API currently support anything like what I described?

Comment: Why not use something other than `GridView`, such as `GridLayout`, `TableLayout`, `LinearLayout`, or `ConstraintLayout`? Or, why not replace all of this (including the `ScrollView`) with a single `RecyclerView`, a `GridLayoutManager`, and custom rules for how many cells the contents take up (so your `TextView`, `EditText`, and `Button` can take up enough cells to span a row)?

Comment: @CommonsWare hm thanks, I will look into it. However, I will lose the ability to use an adapter and custom grid view items.. or will I?

Comment: Not in the `RecyclerView` scenario, as it uses the adapter metaphor (though not the same `Adapter` classes that `GridView` uses).

Comment: Please avoid putting a scrollable View inside another one. You'll most likely get scroll-fight issues.

Comment: @Rotwang that's exactly what I'm not trying to do

Comment: @CommonsWare okay I'll check it out thanks!

Comment: **No**. That's exactly what `GridView inside Scrollview` means: `scrollable inside scrollable`.

Comment: @Rotwang please read my question

Comment: Maybe **you** should read it again.

Comment: @Rotwang nice dude

Answer (score 0):

You can achive it by putting all inside a RelativeLayout and then put RelativeLayout inside ScrollView. Here is the example:

```
<ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout>
<TextView />
<ExitText />
<GridView />
<Button />
<RelativeLayout/>
<ScrollView/>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. Mind explaining why this would work?

Comment: Please avoid putting a scrollable View inside another one.